# Delphi 10 OpenURL on IOS

Tags: ios, delphi, openurl

I am using Delphi 10

In older RAD Studio Versions for iOS it was possible to use `openURL` with SharedApplication in `Apple.Utils.pas`

But `Apple.Utils.pas` cannot be found, in what unit can I find `SharedApplication` and `openURL` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find `SharedApplication` and `openURL` in `iOSapi.UIKit`, you will also need `iOSapi.foundation, Macapi.Helpers`

And to use it, you will need a `SharedApplication` Object and a `NSURL` object that contains the address you would like to navigate to

```
uses iOSapi.UIKit,iOSapi.foundation, Macapi.Helpers
var
    App : UIApplication;
    url : NSurl;
begin
    App := TUIApplication.Wrap(TUIApplication.OCClass.sharedApplication);
    url := TNSURL.Wrap(TNSURL.OCClass.URLWithString(StrToNSStr('http://www.stackoverflow.com')));
    if App.canopenURL(url) then //Check if there is a default App that can open the URL
      App.openURL(url) else
        ShowMessage('Can not open URL');
end;
```

Comment: Hey , thanks for your answer but when i try to implement UIKit ore foundation ore some other Units i get an error : "Unit-Name (for example )IOSapi.UIKit  cannot be resolved . But i am sure the unit is available because i checked it out and found all the units at C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\17.0\source\rtl\ios

Comment: Check you library paths, but just copying IOSapi.UIKIT.pas to your project folder would also work